# Entire data is not getting displayed with iframe

Tags: jquery, python, iframe, flask, socket.io

I have a web application using Flask. I have got to do iframe of a web page(say url:port1) in another(say url:port2) on the same server. I am getting continuous live data in url:port1 but it's not getting exactly reflected on url:port2 wiht iframe. I am missing the data that is coming during the page(url:port2) reload.

I can see all the data on url:port1. I want to show it as it is on url:port2 using the `iframe`. How can I achieve this? Also, is this a usual behaviour of the `iframe`? 
By the way, I am getting all the data on url:port1 with flask socketio.

**UPDATE 1** - Adding code details for more detailed explanation.

The following is the code for the page coming up on url:port1

```
{% block body %}
<div class="table-responsive" id="logs"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var temp_data
// Connecting to socket and getting the data.
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
localStorage.setItem('temp_inc', 0);
socket.on('connect', function() {
document.getElementById('logs').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('data');
    console.log("connected")
    socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
        if (temp_data == null) {
            temp_data = ' '
        }
    temp_data = temp_data + msg.data + '<br>'
    //Storing the data to local storage.
    localStorage.setItem("data", localStorage.getItem("data") + temp_data)
    disc_var = localStorage.getItem('temp_inc');
    disc_var = disc_var + 1;
    // Getting the data from local storage to not to miss the data even after page reload.
    localStorage.setItem('temp_inc', disc_var);
        $('#log').append('<p>Received: ' + msg.data + '</p>');
    if (window.performance) {
        console.info("window.performance work's fine on this browser");
    }
    if (performance.navigation.type == 1 && localStorage.getItem('temp_inc') == 1 || localStorage.getItem('temp_inc') == '01') {
            console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
        } else {
            console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
    }
    // Displaying the data in the logs div.
    document.getElementById('logs').innerHTML += msg.data + "<br>";
    });
}); 
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I get continuous data to the above web page(using flask-socketio). I want to show this page as it is in url:port2. The following shows how I am trying to display the above page(url:port1) in url:port2. But on url:port2, I am not seeing exactly same as I see on url:port1.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="logs">
        <div class="panel-heading">Logs</div>
        <iframe src="url:port1" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        </iframe>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your description is very confusing. Please make it clearer and the code related to the proplem.

Comment: I have included the code snippets @Klaus D.